# When thread's destructor is being called?

Tags: c++, stdthread

I came across an example of basic `std::thread` usage from "The C++ programming language" by Bjarne Stroustrup, and it confuses me. Here is the example:

```
void run(int i, int n) // warning: really poor code
{
    thread t1 {f};
    thread t2;
    vector<Foo> v;
    // ...
    if (i<n)
    {
        thread t3 {g};
        // ...
        t2 = move(t3); // move t3 to outer scope
    }
    v[i] = Foo{}; // might throw
    // ...
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

As Stroustrup writes:

> we may never reach the two `join()`s at the end. In that case, the destructor for `t1` will terminate the program.

But, in which case is `t1`'s destructor called? The `t1` thread is not going out of its scope. There is no explicit `delete` call, either.

I tried to run this code with appropriate changes, but still I couldn't find how `t1`'s destructor is being called.

Comment: When `run` returns the local variables get out of scope and are destroyed (and the destructor for `t1` etc. is called).

Comment: Other than an infinite loop (in which case `run()` will never return, and locally constructed objects never destroyed) the only things that can happen to cause the `join()`s to be never reached are an exception being thrown (possibly by a called function) or a `return` statement in preceding code within `run()`.   In both cases, all locally constructed objects (of automatic storage duration) are destroyed, in reverse order of their construction, and their destructors called/invoked.   Since `t1` is constructed before `t2`, it is destructed last.

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3a5c705fded5f92)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, in which case is `t1`'s destructor called? The `t1` thread is not going out of its scope. There is no explicit `delete` call, either.

The code specifically says that the line `v[i] = Foo{};` may throw an exception. If that happens, control never reaches the line `t1.join();` afterwards in the same block scope, but all local variables of the scope, including `t1`, are still destroyed and their destructors called.

When the destructor of `std::thread` is called while the thread is neither joined nor detached, then the destructor will call `std::terminate` which terminates the whole program by default, via a call to `std::abort`.

More generally, the code is broken unless you can be sure that nothing before the `.join` calls will throw an exception. If you can't be sure of that, then you must wrap it in `try { /*...*/ } catch(...) { t1.join(); throw; }`. Technically, you need to do the same for `t2` separately as well, since `t1.join()` is also allowed to throw, although that might be a situation in which your program will have major problems to continue execution anyway.

With C++20, you can use `std::jthread` to avoid such problems.